# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'predict'. Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, attributeerror

I am working on an RL problem and I created a class to initialize the model and other parameters. The code is as follows:

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, state_size, is_eval=False, model_name=""):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = 20 # measurement, CNOT, bit-flip
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=1000)
        self.inventory = []
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.is_eval = is_eval
        self.done = False

        self.gamma = 0.95
        self.epsilon = 1.0
        self.epsilon_min = 0.01
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.995


    def model(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(units=16, input_dim=self.state_size, activation="relu"))
        model.add(Dense(units=32, activation="relu"))
        model.add(Dense(units=8, activation="relu"))
        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation="softmax"))
        model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=0.003))
        return model

    def act(self, state):
        options = self.model.predict(state)
        return np.argmax(options[0]), options
```

I want to run it for only one iteration, hence I create an object and I pass a vector of length `16` like this:

```
agent = Agent(density.flatten().shape)
state = density.flatten()
action, probs = agent.act(state)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                       Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-14-4f0ff0c40f49> in <module>
----> 1 action, probs = agent.act(state)

<ipython-input-10-562aaf040521> in act(self, state)
     39 #             return random.randrange(self.action_size)
     40 #         model = self.model()
---> 41         options = self.model.predict(state)
     42         return np.argmax(options[0]), options
     43 

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

What's the issue? I checked some other people's codes as well, like [this](https://github.com/Alexander-H-Liu/Policy-Gradient-and-Actor-Critic-Keras/blob/master/agent_dir/agent_pg.py) and I think mine is also very similar.

Let me know.

**EDIT:**

I changed the argument in `Dense` from `input_dim` to `input_shape` and `self.model.predict(state)` to `self.model().predict(state)`.

Now when I run the NN for one input data of shape `(16,1)`, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have
>   3 dimensions, but got array with shape (16, 1)

And when I run it with shape `(1,16)`, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have
>   3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 16)

What should I do in this case?

Comment: You have a function and a variable with the same name (model), that's a bad idea

Comment: In the link, the person has also done the same thing. A lot of coders write their this way. Even I find it very strange. But apparently, that's how people are writing their code.

Comment: No, the code in the link is different, there is no function called model(), which is the core of your problem.

Comment: Okay. So now, I have changed the name of the function to `model_rl`. Even changed the name in line to `options = self.model_rl.predict(state)`. I'm still getting the error

Comment: I think you have a big conceptual misunderstanding, that's not what I told you to do. You can change the name of the function, but then you have to call it and assign the return value of the function call to a variable (with a different name), from where you can call predict.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm missing something here. What do you suggest I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in last code block,

```
def act(self, state):
        options = self.model.predict(state)
        return np.argmax(options[0]), options
```

self.model is a function which is returning a model, it should be self.model().predict(state)

Comment: I'm getting this error:


`TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'.`

Comment: Can you post full stack trace, where you are getting this error?

Comment: `40 #             return random.randrange(self.action_size)

     41 #         model = self.model()

---> 42         options = self.model().predict(state)

     43         return np.argmax(options[0]), options

     44 

<ipython-input-18-417404b4f01d> in model(self)

     28     def model(self):

     29         model = Sequential()

---> 30         model.add(Dense(units=16, input_dim=self.state_size, activation="relu"))

     31         model.add(Dense(units=32, activation="relu"))

     32         model.add(Dense(units=8, activation="relu"))`

Comment: _density.flatten().shape_ is a tuple which you are passing as _state_size_ in Agent class which is being set as input_dim in Dense layer which doesn't take tuple as input. _input_dim_ is number of dimensions of the features.

Answer (score 0):

I used `np.reshape`. So in this case, I did

`density_test = np.reshape(density.flatten(), (1,1,16))`

and the network gave the output.